# Bluebird promises in NodeJS, not getting to then

Tags: node.js, typescript, couchdb, bluebird, couchdb-nano

I'm attempting to use bluebird promises in NodeJs with nano a library used with couchDb. I use the promisfy and when I look get the new async methods.  In the following example, the `nano.db.listAsync` call works out fine, but I never get to the .then or the .catch.

What is wrong here?

```js
   var nano = require('nano')(this.appInfo.dbServiceUrlPrefix);
        Promise.promisifyAll(nano);
        Promise.promisifyAll(nano.db);

       var p = nano.db.listAsync(function(err,body) {
            // get all the DBs on dbServiceUrlPrefix
            var dbNames:string[] = <string[]> body ;
            console.log("allDbs",dbNames) ;
            return dbNames ;
        }).then(function (e:any) {
            console.log('Success',e);
        }).catch(function(e:any){
            console.log('Error',e);
        });
```

Comment: So, your syntax is not plain Javascript.  What language is it?  Can you please tag your question appropriately for that language?

Comment: you might be interested in https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano-blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong.

1. After promisification and calling the promsified version, you use `.then()` to get the result.
2. The `.then()` resolve handler has no `err` variable any more.  If there's an error, the `.then()` reject handler is called.

So, I think you want something like this:

```
   var nano = require('nano')(this.appInfo.dbServiceUrlPrefix);
   Promise.promisifyAll(nano);
   Promise.promisifyAll(nano.db);

   nano.db.listAsync().then(function(body) {
        // get all the DBs on dbServiceUrlPrefix
        var dbNames:string[] = <string[]> body ;
        console.log("allDbs",dbNames) ;
        return dbNames;
    }).then(function (e:any) {
        console.log('Success',e);
    }).catch(function(e:any){
        console.log('Error',e);
    });
```

P.S. Are you sure there are not supposed to be any function arguments passed to `nano.db.listAsync()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the function parameters you pass to `nano.db.listAsync()` are incorrect. It would not have `err` parameter after promissification, so your code should look something like this:

```
var nano = require('nano')(this.appInfo.dbServiceUrlPrefix);
    Promise.promisifyAll(nano);
    Promise.promisifyAll(nano.db);

    var p = nano.db.listAsync(function(body) {
        ...
```

Comment: I've tried that. it comes up null. if I look at the prototype, the listAsync takes arg1,arg2, arg3. when I tried these, the 2nd argument had the body, the third looked like the request. The first I suspect to be the err.